# Filter + Mean Calculation: Argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I try to calculate the mean of the variable pci for a filtered subset of my dataframe country_hsproduct4digit_year. I'm filtering for the product code "3510". Despite pci being numeric and having excluded NA's I still get the above-mentioned error message when using the following code: `filter(country_hsproduct4digit_year, hs_product_code=="3510")%>%mean(country_hsproduct4digit_year$pci, na.rm=TRUE)`
Can you help me with this? I have also tried the mean command with [ brackets and I also checked that hs_product_code is a character variable.

Comment: I'd say the issue is how you use the `%>%` operator. In your code, you are passing the output of the filter operation as input to the `mean` function - which is the whole data frame. However, in `mean` you are again refering to the column of a data frame by providing the "fully-qualified" name dataframename$columnname. This is kind of "redundant".

So as Ronak has pointed out, make sure that you are pulling out the respective cloumn using the `pull` function.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `mean(country_hsproduct4digit_year$pci, na.rm=TRUE)` you are still taking `mean` from the complete dataframe. Try :

```
library(dplyr)

result <- country_hsproduct4digit_year %>%
  filter(hs_product_code=="3510") %>%
  pull(pci) %>%
  mean(na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my problem so quickly. Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(country_hsproduct4digit_year)[hs_product_code == '3510"][, mean(pci, na.rm = TRUE)]
```